# How does Haskell know to stop executing a recursive function on an infinite list?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I’m going through Learn You Some Haskell. In the chapter on recursive function the author redefines two from the standard library:

```
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take' n _
    | n <= 0 = []
take' _ [] = []
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n-1) xs

repeat' :: a -> [a]
repeat' x = x:repeat' x
```

I don’t understand why `take’ 5 (repeat’ 3)` wouldn’t run forever. I understand lazy eval, but in this case I would think that `repeat’` will always be called. How does `take’` limit it?

Comment: Why do you think it will always be called? When exactly will it be called?

Comment: `repeat’` has no edge case. It never exits.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't stop producing values, that's the point of `repeat`. But there is no problem if you stop consuming them - you say you did understand lazy evaluation?

Comment: I think I just got it. I was thinking `x:repeat’ x` was evaluated all at once. Meaning that when `x` is taken, `repeat’ x` would be evaluated too. I guess the compiler is smart enough not to do the second until needed? Thanks, your rude answer forced me to think about it differently. Why would I use AI when I can be belittled by someone with 640k karma here?

Comment: I did not mean to sound rude or belittle anyone. I just wanted you to explain your thinking, so that we can answer accordingly - or think about it again, which apparently helped. Yes, `x:…` is constructed in one step, `repeat' x` is only evaluated in another step later, when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of Haskell has the nice property that you can simply replace expressions with their definitions.

We can use this property to reason about the example you provided:

```
take’ 5 (repeat’ 3)          -- starting expression
take’ 5 (3 : repeat’ 3)      -- replace repeat’ with its definition
3 : take’ 4 (repeat’ 3)      -- replace take’ with its definition
3 : take’ 4 (3 : repeat’ 3)  -- replace repeat’ with its definition
... etc ...
3 : 3 : 3 : 3 : take’ 1 (repeat’ 3)
3 : 3 : 3 : 3 : take’ 1 (3 : repeat’ 3)
3 : 3 : 3 : 3 : 3 : take’ 0 (repeat’ 3)
3 : 3 : 3 : 3 : 3 : []
```